# error: cannot find symbol new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, flutter, dart

Well i'm trying to import Java code from flutter with PlatformChannels, i'm on Ubuntu and i get that error, maybe it's a Java error, y create my project

`flutter create -a java batterylevel`
And i follow the documentation on this link
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab

I have this Java File (same at docs)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
              int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

              if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                result.success(batteryLevel);
              } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
              }
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        );
  }

  private int getBatteryLevel() {
    int batteryLevel = -1;
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
      batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
    } else {
      Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
          registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
      batteryLevel = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100) /
          intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    }

    return batteryLevel;
  }

}
```

And this flutter code (like as docs)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');

  String _batteryLevel = 'Unknown battery level.';

  Future<void> _getBatteryLevel() async {
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
      batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
    }

    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get Battery Level'),
              onPressed: _getBatteryLevel,
            ),
            Text(_batteryLevel),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and i have path of my Java on vscode OpenJDK11: "java.home": "/home/felipe/jdk1.8.0_111"

Anybody know what's wrong? Maybe linux platform or Java, or my code, i hope you can help me, thank you!!!

Comment: I open in Android Studio and i get error in every line of code, (On Java) but flutter doctor no found any issue

Answer (score 1):

I found myself my issue, i was working with a old version and i wasn't in channel stable, when i upgrade my flutter SDK to version 1.17 and change channel, it works.